# multiple functions is one big function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, crud

so I'm writing `DataBase` class which will be an encapsulation layer between `PHP Controller` and `MySQL View`.

```
interface iDataBase {
    public function drug($action, $drug);
    public function company($action, $company);
    public function activeIngredient($action, $activeIngredient);
}
```

At First I thought of making all setters and getters seperate like getAllDrugs(), updateDrug(), removeDrug(), getForUpdate(), getDrug() and so one, but then I realised that I was polluting database interface with too much functions, plus this is a very small-scale version, I'm considering adding much-more classes and much more functionality. So, instead of using a lot of function I just setteled for 3. `$action` will determine what kind of thing does user want to do with certain class. so, for now, possible actions are these: `"add", "getAll", "getForUpdate", "update", "remove"`

but these functions masked by `$action` have different things to do, so their their return result is different and second argument can also be different.

Is my solution a good practice? I'm sure many of you had the same problem, how did you solve it? Are there any possible problems?

P.S. `Drug, Company, ActiveIngredient` are all classes

Comment: Fairly big topic. I would recommend to get into this by reading "clean code / martin c. robert". Great guy!

Comment: I would suggest, if you really want to go down this road, to buffer the Variables in the Class and then create Getters and Setters. Of course it depends on how deep of an abstractation you want and how much effort you want to put into each of these interfaces. I personally wouldn't go by table or database but by logical units. E.g. create a class Customers for all your customers even if it has several tables lying behind it. This makes much more sense than abstracting the tables themself.

Comment: Here's a hint: your database interface should consist of nothing more than things like `query`, `getResult`, `connect`, etc. Your 'model' classes such as `Drug`, `Company` and `ActiveIngredient` may make use these methods on a separate database class.

Comment: @xXx I completely agree that there is no need for every table to have a separate class, but thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @RobMasters I have thought of going that way too, I even read some ready codes, which just use connect, disconnect and query, but I don't think that is way to go for me. I specifically don't want Drug, Company, ActiveIngredient to connect to database. But maybe I'll create another abstraction layer between my DataBase and your one. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: @Ron Maybe If I have free time, I'll look into it, thanks for the reference ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function should have clearly defined, narrow responsibilities with clearly defined, minimalist return types. If you start to create "god functions" which do everything and the kitchen sink depending on what arguments you pass, you're going heavily into the territory of hard to maintain spaghetti code. You do not want a function that does A and returns B if you pass it X, but does C and returns D if you pass it Y etc...

It is a good idea to start *concrete* and generalize over time as you see similar patterns emerge. So, create the methods you actually need:

```
public function findUserById($id)
public function findUserByEmail($email)
public function updateCompanyName($id, $newName)
```

If you find you have shared code between these functions, unify the code behind the scenes to keep it DRY:

```
public function findUserById($id) {
    return $this->find('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', $id);
}

public function findUserByEmail($email) {
    return $this->find('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', $email);
}

protected function find($query, $arg) {
    ...
}
```

Don't start the other way around, thinking you "only need X,Y and Z" which seem similar enough to be unified into one method, then later finding out there are small differences between X, Y and Z and littering your code with special cases for each. That just leads to functions which are either ginormous or so general they basically do nothing on their own.

Comment: I think, you are right. Nevertheless, I whould suggest another solution for this. In my opinion, `findUserById` should not return an array, but an popo-object (just my flavor). `findUserByEmail` should return the `id`, because `findUserById` should be the only responsible function to return the "user". `find` should return only a simple array which contains the ids. `updateCompanyName`? Again, too much responabilities. You have to call the implicit `save`-method again and again. As I said below, this topic is fairly big...

Comment: @Ron Sure, these are just very general examples. I'm not advocating exactly this code, just illustrating the way of thinking.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. I feared that making "god-like" functions would create long term problems of of later maintaining. I guess you are right and making functions do specific things is the way to go. Thanks for very detailed and easy-to-understand answer ;)

Comment: Its worth to mention, that you should invest some time to start with a good structure as a growing application quickly becomes painful to refactor - especially with php because of the missing requirement of typehinting, the lack of scalar typehinting and as a cause of that: tooling. Another point is, that you should face recurring patterns in a similar way, which also helps you to better get into and maintain your application over time. Next: Never miss the phpdoc-based typedefinitions. Higher level IDEs then are able to guide you with autocompletion and some refactoring assistment.

Answer (score 2):

What you are likely looking for is called a [TableDataGateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) (emphasis mine):

> A Table Data Gateway holds *all the SQL for accessing a* ***single*** *table* or view: selects, inserts, updates, and deletes. Other code calls its methods for all interaction with the database.

This means you will have one generic database adapter, for instance a PDO object. You inject this into your various TDG's. The TDG's then use that adapter to CRUD data from the database.

#### Example

```
class CompanyTableGateway
{
    private $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(DBAdapter $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function create($name, $street, $whatever)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter->exec( 'INSERT INTO companies …' );
    }

    public function findById($id) 
    {
        return $this->dbAdapter->exec(
            sprintf('SELECT * from companies where id = %d', $id)
        );
    }

    // more methods …
}
```

If you have multiple of these Gateways, you can abstract the general CRUD logic into an Abstract class and then extend the concrete Gateways from it.

You will then use a [TableModule](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html) or similar other object to call the methods on the individual Gateways.

Answer (score 1):

The never ending discussion of Separation of Concerns vs Single Responsibility Principle.

- Separation of Concerns (SoC) – is the process of breaking a computer program into distinct features that overlap in functionality as little as possible. A concern is any piece of interest or focus in a program. Typically, concerns are synonymous with features or behaviors.
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns
- Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) – every object should have a single responsibility, and that all its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. On some level Cohesion is considered as synonym for SRP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Try to get the best of both, and model your classes accordingly.

Comment: I have never heard of any of those things. I will definitely look into it. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend you doing is do a global database class, which controls the basic input / output of the database, and then extend this down to each table.

An example of this could be a Users table. What you can do to this table is

1. Create
2. Update
3. Delete

You will then extend the Super Database Class, with a Users Class, which will have getters and setters for each function you want to have, ie:

```
class Users extends DatabaseClass {
    public function update ( $params )
    {
        // Make the code for an update, and let the SuperClass execute the code.
        ...
    }

    public function add ( $params )
    {
        ...
    }

    public function delete ( $params )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will allow you to later, easily add more functionality to the Users table, and optimize queries specifically for the table/data you're using.

Comment: Finally I've made up my mind, I'll create DataBase class to handle only CRUD commands.